# Variable binning based on column value

Tags: r

This is difficult to describe (thus the vague title) so I'll just give some example data for what I want. I have two dataframes

```
set.seed(5)    
df = data.frame(ID  = sort(rep(c("2006_01", "2006_02", "2006_03", "2006_04"), length.out = 100)), 
            increment = rep(seq(from = 1, to = 25, by = 1), length.out = 100),
            Var1 = rnorm(100))
```

and

```
set.seed(23)
df2 = data.frame(ID  = sort(rep(c("2006_01", "2006_02", "2006_03", "2006_04"), length.out = 200)), 
             distance = rep(seq(from = 1, to = 50, by = 1), length.out = 200), 
             Var2 = rnorm(200))
```

They are both essentially transects with `$increment` and `$distance` being the measures of how far along the transect the measurements are taken. The longer one has twice as many measurements because it is higher resolution, but it is representing the same transect. I would like to join them based on the proportion of distance through the transect. I calculated a proportion column for each with the following code:

```
df = ddply(df, "ID", transform, proportion = increment/max(increment))
```

and

```
df2 = ddply(df2, "ID", transform, proportion = distance/max(distance))
```

The output I want is, to join the two dataframes (keeping `Var1` and `Var2`). Because `df2` is higher resolution, the only way to join it to `df` is to bin it, but my real data isn't as regular as the sample data, so I need to dynamically bin based on the `proportion` columns so that it's calculating the means in `df2` for proportion values that fall between each set of proportion values in `df`

To try and summarize, I'm trying to join to sets of data that have different resolutions by calculating the mean values of the higher resolution data set of all the points that fall within the resolution of the lower resolution set.

-edit to try and add desired output-

The first few lines of the output dataframe would look like the following:

```
ID        increment        Var1           Var2
2006_001         1  -0.84085548     -0.1207349
2006_001         2   1.38435934       1.353328
2006_001         3  -1.25549186       1.052048
2006_001         4   0.07014277      0.3705596
```

Comment: It would help if, in addition to the well-structured sample data, you provided some expected output. To do that, I recommend you included a call to `set.seed` so that we can have *identical* random data, and you can list the top (or middle or bottom) few rows of the desired output.

Comment: @r2evans Updated with the suggested information.

Comment: Better, thanks. It can be problematic joining/merging on a floating-point field ([R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)). Is this solid enough that you can do (for instance) `as.integer(100*distance/max(distance))` (same for `increment`) and look for identical integers? Or perhaps you should tell us how your bins are constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to through some tidyverse packages.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # nest, unnest
library(purrr) # pmap
```

Since the two data.frames are different dimensions, I find it's nice to `nest` the data into a column.

```
df2 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    proportion = (distance - min(distance)) / diff(range(distance))
  ) %>%
  nest(.key = "dist")
df2
# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#        ID              dist
#    <fctr>            <list>
# 1 2006_01 <tibble [50 × 3]>
# 2 2006_02 <tibble [50 × 3]>
# 3 2006_03 <tibble [50 × 3]>
# 4 2006_04 <tibble [50 × 3]>

df3 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    proportion = (increment - min(increment)) / diff(range(increment))
  ) %>%
  nest(.key = "incr") %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "ID") %>%
  mutate(
    incr = pmap(list(incr, dist),
                function(a, b) {
                  zz <- tail(a$proportion, n = -1) -
                    (tail(a$proportion, n = -1) - head(a$proportion, n = -1)) / 2
                  a$Var2 <- as.numeric(
                    by(b$Var2, cut(b$proportion, c(-1, zz, 2), labels = FALSE), mean)
                  )
                  a
                })
  )
```

Now that things are set up in `df2`, we start by doing the same in `df`, and combine them side-by-side:

```
df3 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    proportion = (increment - min(increment)) / diff(range(increment))
  ) %>%
  nest(.key = "incr") %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "ID")
df3
# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#        ID              incr              dist
#    <fctr>            <list>            <list>
# 1 2006_01 <tibble [25 × 3]> <tibble [50 × 3]>
# 2 2006_02 <tibble [25 × 3]> <tibble [50 × 3]>
# 3 2006_03 <tibble [25 × 3]> <tibble [50 × 3]>
# 4 2006_04 <tibble [25 × 3]> <tibble [50 × 3]>
```

Note that this allows us to associate `x` rows of one data.frame with `y` rows of another, when joined via `ID`.

```
df3 %>%
  mutate(
    incr = pmap(list(incr, dist),
                function(a, b) {
                  # offset between breaks, ...
                  breaks <- tail(a$proportion, n = -1) -
                    (tail(a$proportion, n = -1) - head(a$proportion, n = -1)) / 2
                  # ... with bookends to ensure 100% membership
                  breaks <- c(-1, breaks, 2)
                  a$Var2 <- as.numeric(
                    by(b$Var2, cut(b$proportion, breaks), mean)
                  )
                  a
                })
  ) %>%
  select(ID, incr) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(-proportion)
# # A tibble: 100 × 4
#         ID increment        Var1        Var2
#     <fctr>     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1  2006_01         1 -0.84085548 -0.12073489
# 2  2006_01         2  1.38435934  1.35332759
# 3  2006_01         3 -1.25549186  1.05204780
# 4  2006_01         4  0.07014277  0.37055960
# 5  2006_01         5  1.71144087  0.81060839
# 6  2006_01         6 -0.60290798 -0.41412345
# 7  2006_01         7 -0.47216639  0.09643082
# 8  2006_01         8 -0.63537131 -0.45411977
# 9  2006_01         9 -0.28577363 -0.48124606
# 10 2006_01        10  0.13810822  0.34763251
# # ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: Wow, it's going to take me a bit to work through what all this is doing, but it looks like it does what I want it to, thank you!